# Cannot include css in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I come on CherryPy from PHP, but I have problem. I created in Eclipse project ( PyDev cherrypy ) and it shows in browser basic html but for some reason it want include css and js files. I included just like in php ( html, there is css folder, relative path is ok  )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

but it doesn't show. Below is my project screenshot. Can anybody tell em how to include in CherryPy css ?
  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

specify css and js and images dirs as an static directories in the configuration:

```
[/css]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "static"
```

for more info on how to write `site.config` file:

http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/StaticContent